# php artisan storage:link on shared Hosting is not showing images

Tags: laravel, symlink, laravel-storage

I have been working on a laravel app so for security reason I've placed all of my public files inside the base folder located in public_html and other files have been placed in the public_html/secondBase.

Now when I execute the command: ***php artisan storage:link*** the following error appears.

```
 ErrorException

  symlink(): No such file or directory

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:265
    261|      */
    262|     public function link($target, $link)
    263|     {
    264|         if (! windows_os()) {
  > 265|             return symlink($target, $link);
    266|         }
    267|
    268|         $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    269|
```

I tired the solution below

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path() . '/public_html/base';
    });
}
```

the second method that I've tried is by making the file **symlink.php**, but the images are still broken.

**symlink.php**

```
<?php 
symlink('/home/hmm/public_html/secondBase/storage/app/public','/home/hmm/public_html/base/storage');
```

and finally I made this route where the first error appears.

```
Route::get('/clear', function () {
       
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    Artisan::call('storage:link', [] );
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Go to /public directory and run:

    rm storage

    Go to Laravel root directory and run:

    php artisan storage:link
```

This problem comes when laravel project is moved/copied to some other folder.

The storage link is still there thus causing the exception error. public/storage folder exists and points to wrong location and it needs to be deleted with rm storage command.

After that run php artisan storage:link in terminal and it will create the storage link.

This needs to be done EVERY time when laravel is moved/copied/deployed!

Comment: You need to add the flag for folder removal to e.g. `rm -fr storage` and this will result in `Please provide a valid cache path` error.